# What is the name of this logic circuit?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra

Sorry for dumb question, I'm really newbie in electronic.

As I wrote in topic, What's the name of this circuit? Dose the circuit has any specific name at all ?

[image]

Comment: It doesn't have a name. Just something someone made up.

Comment: It's a NOR gate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overall diagram probably doesn't have a name. It shows two LEDs that are always going to light up together; if you were designing something systematically you probably wouldn't duplicated like that.

(Of course duplication is sometimes what you want. A circuit to systematically duplicate a given signal probably does have a name.)

The individual components you're looking at are NAND gates. It's a neat fact that any logic gate can be built from NAND gates.
For example if you feed both inputs with a single signal (as happens several times in your diagram) then you've made a NOT gate.
Put a NOT gate on each of the inputs of a NAND and you've built an OR gate, which is what the first half of the diagram shows.

**If we ignore the duplication that's happening at the end, then what we're looking at is a NOR gate made out of NAND gates.**

Such patterns might be useful if you want to keep a very narrow inventory of bread-board components, or you have a super-refined process for etching one single kind of gate into a silicon wafer.

Comment: I believe that back in the 1990's, there was a flavor of ASIC that was just a sea of NAND gates; the customer got to specify one or two mask layers to connect them up into a logic chip.

Comment: A possible reason for the final gates in that circuit would be for additional drive current -- although if you're *really* driving an LED from a logic chip you should have a current-limit resistor in there someplace (not to mention a VCC or ground connection).